# How to calculate the area of one of the smaller loops of the curve: $(y^2−x^2)(2x^2−5x+3) =4(x^2−2x+y^2)^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, area, curves, plane-curves

How to calculate the area of one of the smaller loops of the curve: $$(y^2−x^2)(2x^2−5x+3) =4(x^2−2x+y^2)^2$$?
[image]

Comment: What is the context of the problem and please [add more detail](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: do you have a final solution?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha cannot find a general anti derivative for a branch of the function [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1-sqrt%28-6+x%5E2+-+sqrt%283%29+sqrt%28-%28x+-+1%29%5E2+%2820+x%5E2+-+28+x+-+3%29%29+%2B+11+x+%2B+3%29%2F%282+sqrt%282%29%29), so good luck.

Comment: Parametrizing the curve via adjoint curves I get the integral

$\int_{-1.205651455247495}^{0.3077356935911356} 
 \frac{\sqrt{9200t^8+5200sqrt{23}t^7-54860t^6-53440\sqrt{23}t^5-159328t^4+105664\sqrt{23}t^3+1013749t^2+150878\sqrt{23}t+190463}+330*t^3+312\sqrt{23}t^2+2301t+249\sqrt{23}}{200t^4+200\sqrt{23}t^3+2340t^2+640\sqrt{23}t+1580} (-\frac{2t^4+2\sqrt{23}t^3-87t^2-56\sqrt{23}t-187}{20t^4+20\sqrt{23}t^3+234t^2+64\sqrt{23}t+158})'dt$

Comment: Which maple evaluates to about $0.057$

Comment: Can you differentiate and apply Green's thm with line integral $ 2 A= \int ( x dy - y dx) ?$

Comment: @piteer I find it strange that, not only here, but in many of your questions, you don't **dialog** with people, beginning by answering to the questions they place in comments. Try to do it, you will see, it' rewarding...

Answer (score 2):

In maxima using the [adjoint curves method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4165938/28956)

```
solve((y^2-(-1/10)^2)*(2*(-1/10)^2-5*(-1/10)+3)-4*((-1/10)^2-2*(-1/10)+y^2)^2); # [y = -sqrt(23)/10,y = sqrt(23)/10]
solve([a5,a0+a1+a2+a3+a4+a5,a0-a1+a2+a3-a4+a5,(-1/10)*(-1/10)*a0+(-1/10)*(sqrt(23)/10)*a1+(-1/10)*a2+(sqrt(23)/10)*(sqrt(23)/10)*a3+(sqrt(23)/10)*a4+a5],[a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]); # [[a0 = %r1,a1 = -%r2,a2 = (sqrt(23)*%r2-2*%r1)/3, a3 = -(sqrt(23)*%r2+%r1)/3,a4 = %r2,a5 = 0]]
factor(resultant((y^2-x^2)*(2*x^2-5*x+3)-4*(x^2-2*x+y^2)^2,t*x^2-x*y+(sqrt(23)-2*t)/3*x-(sqrt(23)+t)/3*y^2+y,x)); # 18*(x-1)^4*x^2*(10*x+1)*(20*t^4*x+20*sqrt(23)*t^3*x+234*t^2*x+64*sqrt(23)*t*x+158*x+2*t^4+2*sqrt(23)*t^3-87*t^2-56*sqrt(23)*t-187)
factor(resultant((y^2-x^2)*(2*x^2-5*x+3)-4*(x^2-2*x+y^2)^2,t*x^2-x*y+(sqrt(23)-2*t)/3*x-(sqrt(23)+t)/3*y^2+y,x)); # 18*(y-1)^2*y^2*(y+1)^2*(200*t^4*y^2+200*sqrt(23)*t^3*y^2+2340*t^2*y^2+640*sqrt(23)*t*y^2+1580*y^2-660*t^3*y-624*sqrt(23)*t^2*y-4602*t*y-498*sqrt(23)*y-46*t^4+20*sqrt(23)*t^3+897*t^2+313*sqrt(23)*t+782)
solve(200*t^4*y^2+200*sqrt(23)*t^3*y^2+2340*t^2*y^2+640*sqrt(23)*t*y^2+1580*y^2-660*t^3*y-624*sqrt(23)*t^2*y-4602*t*y-498*sqrt(23)*y-46*t^4+20*sqrt(23)*t^3+897*t^2+313*sqrt(23)*t+782,y); # [y = -(sqrt(9200*t^8+5200*sqrt(23)*t^7-54860*t^6-53440*sqrt(23)*t^5-159328*t^4+105664*sqrt(23)*t^3+1013749*t^2+150878*sqrt(23)*t+190463)-330*t^3-312*sqrt(23)*t^2-2301*t-249*sqrt(23))/(200*t^4+200*sqrt(23)*t^3+2340*t^2+640*sqrt(23)*t+1580), y = (sqrt(9200*t^8+5200*sqrt(23)*t^7-54860*t^6-53440*sqrt(23)*t^5-159328*t^4+105664*sqrt(23)*t^3+1013749*t^2+150878*sqrt(23)*t+190463)+330*t^3+312*sqrt(23)*t^2+2301*t+249*sqrt(23))/(200*t^4+200*sqrt(23)*t^3+2340*t^2+640*sqrt(23)*t+1580)]
solve(20*t^4*x+20*sqrt(23)*t^3*x+234*t^2*x+64*sqrt(23)*t*x+158*x+2*t^4+2*sqrt(23)*t^3-87*t^2-56*sqrt(23)*t-187,x); # [x = -(2*t^4+2*sqrt(23)*t^3-87*t^2-56*sqrt(23)*t-187)/(20*t^4+20*sqrt(23)*t^3+234*t^2+64*sqrt(23)*t+158)]
solve(-(2*t^4+2*sqrt(23)*t^3-87*t^2-56*sqrt(23)*t-187)/(20*t^4+20*sqrt(23)*t^3+234*t^2+64*sqrt(23)*t+158)-1,t),float; # [t = -2.444534971313947,t = -1.453380790342413,t = -1.205651455247495, t = 0.3077356935911356]
```

In geogebra; check the parametrization

[image: eq]

In maple; get the area $0.057$

```
int((sqrt(9200*t^8+5200*sqrt(23)*t^7-54860*t^6-53440*sqrt(23)*t^5-159328*t^4+105664*sqrt(23)*t^3+1013749*t^2+150878*sqrt(23)*t+190463)+330*t^3+312*sqrt(23)*t^2+2301*t+249*sqrt(23))/(200*t^4+200*sqrt(23)*t^3+2340*t^2+640*sqrt(23)*t+1580)*diff(-(2*t^4+2*sqrt(23)*t^3-87*t^2-56*sqrt(23)*t-187)/(20*t^4+20*sqrt(23)*t^3+234*t^2+64*sqrt(23)*t+158),t),t=-1.205651455247495..0.3077356935911356); # -0.057
```

In geogebra

[image: wingpoly]

Comment: To go back from the parametrization to the implicit form (in M2) `S=QQ[a,s,t,w,x,y,z,MonomialOrder=>Lex];I=ideal(x+(2*t^4+2*a*t^3*s-87*t^2*s^2-56*a*t*s^3-187*s^4),10*y-w+330*t^3*s+312*a*t^2*s^2+2301*t*s^3+249*a*s^4,z-(20*t^4+20*a*t^3*s+234*t^2*s^2+64*a*t*s^3+158*s^4),w^2-(9200*t^8+5200*a*t^7*s-54860*t^6*s^2-53440*a*t^5*s^3-159328*t^4*s^4+105664*a*t^3*s^5+1013749*t^2*s^6+150878*a*t*s^7+190463*s^8),a^2-23)`
`gens gb I`
`factor oo_0_0` and set $z=1.$

Comment: What is the closed form area or at least a series representation?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Excuse my ignorance, is this a usual request for the integration/area tags? I'm in it for the curves tag. The integral given can be approximated any way you want. The integral limits are also approximations, the exact values are `(-sqrt(((-23^(3/2))-(8*(4*23^(1/2)))/11+(294*23^(1/2))/11)/6+18/11)/2)+((-1)*23^(1/2))/4+3/4`, `sqrt(((-23^(3/2))-(8*(4*23^(1/2)))/11+(294*23^(1/2))/11)/6+18/11)/2+((-1)*23^(1/2))/4+3/4`.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland In this case it becomes a bit simpler because $y$ can be explicitly written in terms of $x$ for points over the curve.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wolfram, The equation for the blue curve is
$$
y = \frac{\sqrt{-6 x^2-\sqrt{3} \sqrt{-(x-1)^2 \left(20 x^2-28 x-3\right)}+11 x+3}}{2
   \sqrt{2}} := g_1(x)
$$

and the equation for the orange curve is
$$
y = \frac{\sqrt{-6 x^2+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{-(x-1)^2 \left(20 x^2-28 x-3\right)}+11 x+3}}{2
   \sqrt{2}}:= g_2(x)
$$

and the points in the smaller loop satisfy $1 \leq x \leq \frac 32$. Using Green's theorem with $Q=x, P = 0$, you have that

$$
\iint_D \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)}_{=1}dx dy  = \int_{\gamma} P dx +Q dy
$$

and so
$$
Area = \int_{\gamma} x \, dy = \int_{\gamma_1} x dy + \int_{\gamma_2} x dy.
$$

Where $\gamma_1$ corresponds to the blue curve, travelled from left to ro right and $\gamma_2$ to the orange curve, travelled from right to left. The line integrals over $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ can be computed using the standard parametrizations associated to the expressions above ($y = g_1(x),\quad y=g_2(x)$):

$$\int_{\gamma_1} x dy = \int_1^{3/2} x g_1 '(x) dx \approx -0.146917$$

$$\int_{\gamma_2} x dy = -\int_1^{3/2} x g_2 '(x) dx \approx 0.204086$$

So, the estimate for the area would be 0.0571698, as pointed out in other answers. I did not try to compute the integrals exactly.

[image]